# Sql Server Simple Query Optimisation

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, query-performance, sqlperformance

I have a simple query joining two tables - T1 (30 million records) and T2 (300 records).

I want all the records in the select query and joining column has only one 3 distinct records in the T1 table. hence the selectivity of this column is very very low.

The query is taking 50 minutes to fetch the data. 
Note- there is no index , no primary key in both the tables.

Is there any way to increase the fetch speed.

Thanks in advance.

```
select *
from dbo.T1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  T2  ON  T2.Columnname = T1.columnname;
```

Comment: is there a reason you dont have any indexes?

Comment: Please post a schema and EXPLAIN.

Comment: No index and no primary key, be prepared to wait a looong time.

Comment: "there is no index, no primary key in both the tables"...
"is there any way to increase the fetch speed"

Hmmm nothing comes to mind. Oh wait...

Seriously though, have you tried creating indexes on the fly in a stroed procedure before running the select?

Comment: Q1: If I create a composite primary key , Would it help to fetch the data faster even if we are not using them in any where clause . 
Q2: I can create an index but the question is On which column should index be created ? As far as I know , index should be created on columns that we use in where condition . but here the column that I am using contains only 3 distinct values. 
Sorry If you find these questions to immature.

Comment: Can you put your execution plan here? https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ 
  Also, check https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/60180/52607